# How should I use Regex in AWS Amplify GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, database, graphql, aws-amplify

So, I want to get the filtered data to my client,
I coded:

```
  async function getData() {
    const exampleData= await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listExample,{
      variables: { limit: 1000 },
      filter: {     
        order_number: {
           regexp: `.*TEST.*` 
          }
      }
    }));
    dispatch({ type: QUERY, example: exampleData.data.listExample.items });
  }
```

But I couldn't receive any data,

Accroding to this document
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/query-data/q/platform/js/#filtering-queries

I tried eq, ne, etc. They all work fine and get filtered data.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't. Since my company's development plan has come to a halt, I am now focusing my attention to other area.....